# FFmpeg VS PyFFmpeg performance wise?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-encoding

Lets say for batch processing of over 10000 videos, is there any thing to be gained from using FFmpeg rather than the pyFFmpeg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that pyFFmpeg is just a wrapper over the libraries, I'd say you shouldn't have any negligible performance difference between the 2, since they use the same libraries at the core.

Comment: how about this then?   Seeking is not performing well on network streams yet. pyffmpeg is currently doing playback only, it does not support encoding pyffmpeg is not designed to take advantage of multithreading yet

Comment: In a case such as that, your only choice would be to use the one that does support those features, if you need them that is. :)